# roslaunch dynamixel

Tags: dynamixel

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi again, here i'm still got problem changing my friend's ros-files electric structure and i want to changed it to indigo.
i've download and install the dynamixel driver by `sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-dynamixel-controllers ros-indigo-dynamixel-driver ros-indigo-dynamixel-msgs ros-indigo-dynamixel-motor` and connect RS232 (for TTL) to AX12+.
Now i got this error when i write `roslaunch <my_package> ZMP_dynamixel.launch`:

```
core service [/rosout] found
process[dynamixel_controller/dynamixel_manager-1]: started with pid [7803]
process[dynamixel_controller/dynamixel_controller_spawner_ax12-2]: started with pid [7804]
[INFO] [WallTime: 1446118639.239715] dynamixel_ax12 controller_spawner: waiting for controller_manager skripsi_dynamixel to startup in /dynamixel_controller/ namespace...
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/opt/ros/indigo/lib/dynamixel_controllers/controller_manager.py", line 245, in <module>
 manager = ControllerManager()
File "/opt/ros/indigo/lib/dynamixel_controllers/controller_manager.py", line 102, in __init__
 serial_proxy.connect()
File "/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dynamixel_driver/dynamixel_serial_proxy.py", line 97, in connect
 self.dxl_io = dynamixel_io.DynamixelIO(self.port_name, self.baud_rate)
File "/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dynamixel_driver/dynamixel_io.py", line 67, in __init__
 self.ser = serial.Serial(port)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/serial/serialutil.py", line 261, in __init__
 self.open()
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/serial/serialposix.py", line 278, in open
 raise SerialException("could not open port %s: %s" % (self._port, msg))
serial.serialutil.SerialException: could not open port /dev/ttyUSB0: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/dev/ttyUSB0'
================================================================================REQUIRED process [dynamixel_controller/dynamixel_manager-1] has died!
process has died [pid 7803, exit code 1, cmd /opt/ros/indigo/lib/dynamixel_controllers/controller_manager.py __name:=dynamixel_manager __log:=/home/adelleodel/.ros/log/8c82747c-7e1d-11e5-bae6-240a6416fc2f/dynamixel_controller-dynamixel_manager-1.log].
log file: /home/adelleodel/.ros/log/8c82747c-7e1d-11e5-bae6-240a6416fc2f/dynamixel_controller-dynamixel_manager-1*.log
Initiating shutdown!
================================================================================
[dynamixel_controller/dynamixel_controller_spawner_ax12-2] killing on exit
[dynamixel_controller/dynamixel_manager-1] killing on exit
```

what should i do now?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/220092/roslaunch-dynamixel/) by [adelleodel](https://answers.ros.org/users/24939/adelleodel/) on ROS Answers with karma: 76 on 2015-10-29

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [zweistein](https://answers.ros.org/users/4023/zweistein/) on 2015-10-29**:
Permission denied for device plugged in, try `$ sudo chmod 777 /dev/ttyUSB0`.

**Comment by [adelleodel](https://answers.ros.org/users/24939/adelleodel/) on 2015-10-29**:
I tried it. But, it said `no such file or directory`

**Comment by [zweistein](https://answers.ros.org/users/4023/zweistein/) on 2015-11-02**:
You should try to list all the plugged in serial communication devices `ls /dev/ttyUSB*`  or all devices like `ls /dev/*`. Another way is to add the user to the group which handles that device `sudo usermod -a -G groupName userName`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hi, had the same problem. go to home directory, give command : chmod 777 /dev/ttyUSB0
this temporarily gives permission to execute ttyUSB0 file by all users , try executing dynamixel_manager.launch twice mine didnt work the first time

---

Originally posted by [karthik.ram](https://answers.ros.org/users/26437/karthik.ram/) with karma: 16 on 2016-03-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [adelleodel](https://answers.ros.org/users/24939/adelleodel/) on 2016-05-25**:
hi, thanks for replying. i had solved the problem just as you said :)

**Comment by [Abdu](https://answers.ros.org/users/30451/abdu/) on 2017-10-15**:
Hi, I have same problem, I use this [driver](https://github.com/arebgun/dynamixel_motor), I run `roslaunch dynamixel_tutorials controller_manager.launch` but no morote are detected ????